# Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app supporting two main windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, multiple-monitors

I need to display two windows on two separate monitors in full screen mode using UWP. Is this possible?  I am using Windows 10. And developing using Visual Studio 2015 update 2.  I can setup the two monitors in "Extend" mode but cannot assume they are the same size.

Any tips will be helpful.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the CoreApplication.CreateNewView() function. Refer to these articles for more details,

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/01/09/be-two-places-at-once-using-multiple-windows/

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2304072&seqNum=2

Answer (score 2):

My previous answer may helps you:

[Multiple instances of a Windows Universal App -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807090/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807090/)

But I have no idea to place the window to the certain display programatically.